# Does Rails create any connection pools to mysql? Is it a single threaded design?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, scalability, passenger

How are connections to mysql handled in Rails 3?

Do multiple connections to the website share the same mysql connection, or does it take a connection from a connection pool and then release it once the request has closed all connections to mysql?

If there are 10 front end servers all hitting a single db server, are there any issues here?

I' using Phusion passenger if that effects anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html) answers by itself:

> A connection pool synchronizes thread access to a limited number of
>   database connections. The basic idea is that each thread checks out a
>   database connection from the pool, uses that connection, and checks
>   the connection back in. ConnectionPool is completely thread-safe, and
>   will ensure that a connection cannot be used by two threads at the
>   same time, as long as ConnectionPool’s contract is correctly followed.
>   It will also handle cases in which there are more threads than
>   connections: if all connections have been checked out, and a thread
>   tries to checkout a connection anyway, then ConnectionPool will wait
>   until some other thread has checked in a connection.